# 0-based line numbering in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-14

Recently I was studying some code. The code was in a language very similar to RedCode. In this language, the code uses 0-based line numbering. IntelliJ numbers lines starting with 1 instead of 0.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Are the line numbers part of the code or just cosmetic?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything in the `Appearance` section of the options (in 13.1.4 anyway); there may be an option for .IntelliJXX\config\options\editor.xml but I'm not sure where you would find it.